# ggplot2: Coordinate legend in a graph with geom_line and geom_point combined together

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the sample data frame:

```
dt <- data.frame(x = 1:6, y2017 = 5:10, y2018 = 12:17, y2019 = 15:20)

#  x y2017 y2018 y2019
#  1     5    12    15
#  2     6    13    16
#  3     7    14    17
#  4     8    15    18
#  5     9    16    19
#  6    10    17    20
```

Here is what I originally did:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = y2017, color = "2017", fill = "2017", shape = "2017"), size = 2) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = y2017, color = "2017")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = y2018, color = "2018", fill = "2018", shape = "2018"), size = 2) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = y2019, color = "2019", fill = "2019", shape = "2019"), size = 2) + 
  ylab("Y") +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "", 
                      breaks = c("2017", "2018","2019"),
                      values = c("#D16103", "#52854C", "#293352")) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "", 
                     breaks = c("2017", "2018","2019"),
                     values = c(3, 4, 21)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", 
                    breaks = c("2017", "2018","2019"),
                    values = c("#D16103", "#52854C", "#293352")) + 
  theme_bw()
```

The resulting graph is:
[image]

For legend `2018` and `2019`, there's a line going through the point and this is not what I wanted. So I tried to move `color` in `geom_line` in `2017` out of `aes()`.

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = y2017, color = "2017", fill = "2017", shape = "2017"), size = 2) + 
# Here is what I change:
  geom_line(aes(y = y2017),  color = "#D16103") +
  geom_point(aes(y = y2018, color = "2018", fill = "2018", shape = "2018"), size = 2) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = y2019, color = "2019", fill = "2019", shape = "2019"), size = 2) + 
  ylab("Y") +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "", 
                      breaks = c("2017", "2018","2019"),
                      values = c("#D16103", "#52854C", "#293352")) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "", 
                     breaks = c("2017", "2018","2019"),
                     values = c(3, 4, 21)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", 
                    breaks = c("2017", "2018","2019"),
                    values = c("#D16103", "#52854C", "#293352")) + 
  theme_bw()
```

Then the result becomes:
[image]

In the legend of `2017`, the line crossing it is no longer there, while `2018` and `2019` are correct.

**I'm wondering if there's a way allowing the combination of the legend of `2017` in the first graph and `2018` and `2019` in the second graph.**

(I know I can use `pivot_longer()` to transform the dataset and make it easier for plotting the legend, but for my main dataset this makes it harder. So I stick to this way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following code to your first part of the program:

```
guides(shape= guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=c("#D16103","#52854C", "#293352"), lty=c(1,0,0) )))
```

Then you will get the following output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks!! That works exactly as I wanted. Could you please elaborate on what `guide` and `guide_legend` do here? I read the documentation but I don't quite fully understand it.

Comment: You are just overriding the color legend (that is removing lines with `lty=0` for 2018 and 2019).  This is generally used to keep a single legend, say, shape, when you have multiple variables in `aes`.  Most of the information is available online.

Answer (score 2):

ggplot is not designed for wide for data structures. Consider the alternative (reshaping into long form).

Or, use `matplot` from the base R **graphics** package, which provides a lot more control and flexibility.

```
cols <- c('red','blue','green3')
pch <- c(3,4,19)

par(mar=c(4,4,1,6), las=1)
matplot(dt[,'x'], dt[,c('y2017', 'y2018', 'y2019')], type="o", pch=pch, col=cols, 
        xlab="x", ylab="Y", lty=c(1,0,0))

legend("right", xpd=NA, inset=-0.3, legend=2017:2019, lty=c(1,0,0), pch=pch, col=cols, bty='n')
grid(col=rgb(0,0,0,0.1))
```

[image]